# Map value of an attribute in one object array to an attribute in another object array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects:

```
courses = [ { _id: 999, courseCode: "Eng1" },
{ _id: 777, courseCode: "Sci1" },
{ _id: 666, courseCode: "Eng2" },
{ _id: 888, courseCode: "Sci2" }  ]

sectionCourses = [ { sectionCode: "1A", courseId: "999" },
{ sectionCode: "1A", courseId: "777" },
{ sectionCode: "2A", courseId: "666" }, 
{ sectionCode: "2A", courseId: "888" }  ]
```

I want to filter the `courses` array in such a way that it contains only the courses that are not in a section.
For example if I select section with `sectionCode: "2A"`, the `courses` array should only contain

```
courses = [ { _id: 999, courseCode: "Eng1" },
    { _id: 777, courseCode: "Sci1" },
    { _id: 888, courseCode: "Sci2" }  ]
```

I tried to do this way:

```
 courses = courses.filter(c => !(sectionCourses.includes(c._id)))
```

but I know this is incomplete because I can't figure out how to access `courseId` in `sectionCourses`.

Please help.

Comment: The question is not clear.Not able to understand how on selecting `2A` will have new array.In new array i can see _id:888

Comment: Do you specifically need to use the filter method? Why not just loop through?

Comment: `includes()` only works to compare whole elements. Use `Array#some()` or `Array#find()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.includes()` method to find the whole object by its `_id`, includes compares the whole objects and doesn't search for a specific property.

What you can do here is to get an array of `courseIds` to be ignored based on the `sectionCode` you provided, and then filter the courses that their `_id` doesn't exist in this array of `ids`:

```
function getCourses(catCode) {

  var coursesIdstoIgnore = sectionCourses.filter(s => s.sectionCode === catCode).map(s => s.courseId);
  return courses.filter(c => coursesIdstoIgnore.indexOf(c["_id"].toString()) == -1);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var courses = [{
    _id: 999,
    courseCode: "Eng1"
  },
  {
    _id: 777,
    courseCode: "Sci1"
  },
  {
    _id: 666,
    courseCode: "Eng2"
  },
  {
    _id: 888,
    courseCode: "Sci2"
  }
];

var sectionCourses = [{
    sectionCode: "1A",
    courseId: "999"
  },
  {
    sectionCode: "1A",
    courseId: "777"
  },
  {
    sectionCode: "2A",
    courseId: "666"
  },
  {
    sectionCode: "2A",
    courseId: "888"
  }
];

function getCourses(catCode) {
  var cousesIdstoIgnore = sectionCourses.filter(s => s.sectionCode === catCode).map(s => s.courseId);
  console.log(cousesIdstoIgnore);

  return courses.filter(c => cousesIdstoIgnore.indexOf(c["_id"].toString()) == -1);

}

var results = getCourses("2A");


console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
courses.filter(course => sectionCourses.find(section => +section.courseId === +course._id))
```

Note how i use the +operator before of the `courseId` and `_id` properties. this automatically turns a String typed number into a Number.
e.g

```
+"1" = 1
+1 = 1
```

This is very useful for slight comparison gotchas when using `===`

*Note* Array.find() doesn't work with IE